# How to use REST in web applications?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

Nowadays i am learning REST but i couldn't understand its way of usage. Probably this is perfectly easy question but since i have lack of knowledge about concepts i am totally confused.

Let say i have a simple `Spring MVC` application and i run [localhost:8080/greeting/?id=1](http://localhost:8080/greeting) and it shows my greeting.html page and some data from my database. So far so good.

But when i change my `@Controller` to `@RestController` and call [localhost:8080/greeting/1](http://localhost:8080/greeting) i get a json as following  `{"id":1,"content":"Hello, World!"}`. I understand this is normal because this is a response of rest service.

But how to use it in my greeting.html? i mean what is the concept to map this data to my html page?

Thanks in advance

Altan

Comment: Typically you would use some client code to get this JSON data. A client could be a JS client executing a HTTP GET request in your greeting.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is RESTful programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple tutorial that explain how to consume RESTful Web Service on **Spring.io** website :

- Consuming a RESTful Web Service with AngularJS : https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/
- Consuming a RESTful Web Service with rest.js : https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-restjs/
- Consuming a RESTful Web Service with Backbone.js : https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-backbone/
- Consuming a RESTful Web Service with jQuery : https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/
- Consuming a RESTful Web Service with Sencha Touch : https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-sencha/

You just have to choose the method with which you are most familiar.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery to parse this json String

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

then your can set value like this

```
<p>Input field: <input type="text" id="test" value="Mickey Mouse"></p>

$("#test").text(obj.name);
```